# Need help to resolve this issue while running flutter code

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-packages

This is the error I'm facing while running flutter programs:

> lib/main.dart: Warning: Interpreting this as package URI,
> 'package:flutter_guide_1/main.dart'.

My code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void mian() {}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Text('Hello!'),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: The code you have shown has obvious typos. The line that you get as a warning is not in your code. Please provide a [mcve] of your problem.

Comment: mian should be main() of course, and your entry function is empty?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to return runApp

```
   void main() => runApp(MyApp());
```

Answer (score 0):

At the top of Android Studio, there is a drop-down menu with targets. It probably says "main.dart".
Inside the box, left of the "main.dart", there is a blue symbol. Either it is an "[ (F) main.dart ]" (the Flutter logo) or it is a Dart-arrow fin logo "[ (X) main.dart ]". It should be the "F" version to build properly, so select that.